# Why is everything bold?

Tags: terminal-emacs

I am running emacs in the terminal inside tmux and everything is bold:

[image]

This is not the case with other terminal applications, e.g. Vim. Is there any way to change this?

**Note:** This is not terminal-dependent; this happens with xterm and with xfce4-terminal, with different fonts.

Comment: What do your xfce4-terminal font settings say?

Comment: Nothing special. As I said, all other applications work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I had a call to `custom-set-faces` in my `.emacs` file. After removing this, the font in the terminal reverted back to normal.